# Вкладки Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, lazyloading, html, css

Есть несколько вкладок с большим количеством картинок. Идея состоит в том, чтобы загружать картинки только текущей вкладки. Для вкладок я использую Jquery UI, для картинок lazyload  метод. Подгружаю картинки только текущей вкладки следующим образом:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
   show: function(event, ui) {  
      $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function(){ 
         var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src"); 
         $(this).attr("src", imageSrc); 
      }); 
   } 
});
```

Некоторые вкладки содержат в себе до 750 картинок. Поэтому возник вопрос - как остановить загрузку текущей вкладки, если была нажата другая вкладка и начать немедленную загрузку картинок из нажатой вкладки?

Answer (score 1):

При переключении в следующий таб у всех картинок этого таба сбросьте src.

Загруженные картинки останутся в кэше, так что вы по идее ничего не теряете.

Когда вы в следующий раз переключитесь на этот таб, src снова установятся, и картинки, которые есть в кэше, сразу загрузятся. Остальные будут грузиться из сети.

ЗЫ: я не спец по js, код не напишу, сорри.

Наверное, что-то вроде

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
     show: function(event, ui) {
         if (oldui != null) { // знатоки, поправьте!
             $('img.lazy', oldui.panel).each(function() { 
                 $(this).attr("src", "");
             });
         }
         oldui = ui;
         $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function() {
             var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src");
             $(this).attr("src", imageSrc);
         });
     }
});
```

(сильно не пинайте!)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо!
В итоге пришел к такому решению:

```
var prevTab = 0;
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: function(event, ui) {
                if(prevTab != ui.index) {
                    $('img.lazy', prevTab.panel).each(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", "");
                    });
                }
                prevTab = ui.index; 
                $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function(){
                    var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src");
                    $(this).attr("src", imageSrc);
                });
            }
        });
```

***UPD*** похоже, что можно получить доступ к последней вкладке и ее содержимому с помощью `ui.oldTab` и `ui.oldPanel`, тогда:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('img.lazy', ui.oldPanel).each(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", "");
                    });
                $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function(){
                    var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original");
                    $(this).attr("src", imageSrc);
                });
            }
        });
```